# Capturing Kinect Audio

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, audio, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to access the audio stream from Kinect's microphone array within ROS? I found a brief reference in the [deprecated kinect stack](http://ros.org/wiki/kinect) but nothing else. A quick Google search indicates that functionality is not available in the OpenNI API at the moment, although the drivers are there.

Does anyone have any pointers that could help me with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43143/capturing-kinect-audio/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-21**:
More info was given on this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/48684/kinect-microphone-array-linux-hark-in-combination-with-openni/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read in ros-users someone is working a [new libfreenect-based ROS driver](http://ros.org/wiki/freenect_stack). I heard it was possible to capture audio in libfreenect, but haven't found any information on how to do it.

I also found out about a library which supposedly supports Kinect audio capture and has an [existing ROS package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hark), [HARK](http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/HARK/wiki.cgi?page=HARK-ROS) (an open-sourced robot audition software).

Haven't tested this out yet, but seems like the way to go so far.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2012-11-17**:
Indeed, one of my colleague, working on audio with kinect is using HARK,and it seems to work pretty well.

**Comment by [dim_sgou](https://answers.ros.org/users/20637/dim_sgou/) on 2014-11-04**:
Those drivers actually work, I have used them to recognize the Kinect microphones and captured the audio stream using the portAudio library.